# How to find cause of exception in a Flutter app using vscode

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I am debugging my flutter application using vscode.

A unhandled exception is thrown and the execution is paused.

The callstack is only three lines deep and only contains "flutter code" so I am unable to see the cause of the exception.

Is it a way to make the callstack deeper so I can see witch line in my code that cause the exception?

Comment: run with -v or -verbose

Comment: I tried that. Did not give me any more information about my problem.

Comment: Can you kindly explain your problem by providing code and the exception you're catching.

Comment: My "question" is not directly related to my code. It's relate to how to use vscode debug capabilities to find errors in my code. My code throws a exception, how can I use vscode to trace this exception back to the error in my code.